# 3.3kV isolated heatsink for TO247 packages

Tags: isolation, heatsink

I want to use some TO247 devices with an enclosure. In fact, I have to and there is no choice.

The enclosure has to withstand a dielectric strength test of 3.3kV for 10sec plus 6.6kV for 20ms. All devices together have power dissipation of 60W.

There is a method required to bring the heat out of the enclosure. If the isolation requirements were not so high, I would choose isolated thermal pads. Those I found can not fulfill this isolation requirement.

There are modules which are sufficiently isolated, but the devices are idle most of the time. This leads to storage issues.

Are there any solutions to bring the heat out of the enclosure, without violating the isolation requirements?

Even ideas are appreciated.

Edit - There are some questions I want to answer:

1. Dimensioning the heatsink is not the issue / obstacle. The issue is the dielectric strength between conducting parts (live parts) and the enclosure (dead metal).
2. I cannot influence the enclosure itself. It is the power distribution in a commercial vehicle.
3. The circuit is to protect and switch consumers, which are used a few times a year only. They might be switched-off for 9 months. Storage-effects for power modules occur when they are not used for a long time. The housing materials and in special encapsulates collect water over time. This leads to corrosion.

Comment: Where are your Rca design specs?   Large heatsinks with fans can be around 1 C/W - much less with much care.

A well heatsunk TO220 can manage Tja = 10C/W without too much effort.

Comment: You will probably need force air cooling.  I did this for a design that I did for AVAYA in Denver (nee Lucent) It used a thermal sensor epoxied to hotspot to regulate an LM317 with a transistor to vary twin 38mm  fan speed in 1U high rack built to UL/CSA/CE  standards. Fan only started slowly at full load.  The trick I invented was Mylar spoiler on air intake to create turbulence over a board to gather more heat

Comment: 10k units /yr, 20 yrs ago

Comment: If you don't care about price, I'm pretty sure there are manufacturers that make custom diamond heatsinks.... but considering the material and the fact that they have to be custom made i imagine the price is going to be far out of anyone's budget.

Comment: You additional explanations make things even more confusing than before. Are you trying to add new circuit to _existing_ enclosure of _some_ device of _some_ vehicle? Yes, the things rust on a long storage, but that is exactly what enclosures are designed to prevent, not to "collect water over time"

Comment: Maple: Yes, I have to add a new circuit in an existing design. Minor changes are possible. About humidity: Power modules, like EconoPack, contain hygroscopic materials. They need to be used to avoid chip-degredation over time. You can find additional information by Infineon, Semikron, Fuji or Mitsubishi.

Comment: Adding 60W heat to existing device without enclosure redesign will most likely make old circuits malfunction, unless it was designed with huge thermal margin to begin with. I suspect this task is not as trivial as selection of correct dielectric.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best solution would be to use aluminum enclosure with heat dissipating ridges and mount devices on thermally conductive insulator. This is quite common approach used by high-power modules, see [Roboteq](https://www.roboteq.com/index.php/roboteq-products-and-services/brushless-dc-motor-controllers/247/hblxxxx-family) motor controllers, for example.

There are tons of [pre-fabricated enclosures](http://www.hammondmfg.com/1455NHD.htm) on the market, but there are also Chinese companies that can make extruded profile of your choice relatively cheap.

For the insulator look for something like [Parker Hannifin](https://ph.parker.com/us/en/cho-therm-thermally-conductive-electrical-insulator-pads) product, they actually sell thermal pads already pre-cut for all common device packages.

Also TO247 package already has mounting hole surrounded by dielectric, you probably wouldn't even need an insert tube for mounting hardware.

You haven't specified the devices you are going to use, but if you can find them in Infineon "advanced isolation" package, you will have 2.5kV/60s isolation already, which means thermal pad can be quite thin.

Comment: Many thanks! I take now the isolation of the part plus additional isolation of pads under account. I will investigate this approach. The products of Parker Hannifin I take under account as well. I found parts with even more than 10kV isolation. I dont need this here, but it might be interesting for other topics.

Answer (score 0):

> If the isolation requirements were not so high, I would choose isolated thermal pads.

Have you considered thermal pads made of alumina (aluminium oxide ceramic) for your power transistors? They get good high voltage insulation.